# How to select more than one image button in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Can I select more than one image button ? for example : I have 4 image buttons, each image button has a different function `onclick`

```
Image_Button_1 = button1()
Image_Button_2 = button2() 
Image_Button_3 = button3() 
Image_Button_4 = button4()
```

I want to make a program for running every function.. if I `select Image_Button_1` and `Image_Button_3`, `button1()` and `button3()` will run

how to select more than image button using shift/ctrl click or anything...

Comment: Please be more precise. Is this a Javascript question or C# Question.?

Comment: ehm, maybe Javascript and C#
because button1() and button3() is C# function and then I don't know how to select more than 1 image button in asp.net

so I think I need jquery / javascript function for help my problem...

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using javascript or jquery then event delegation might help you

[What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)